# Como aplicar regex , utilizando C# em um arquivo pdf?

Tags: c#, regex, pdf

```
    private static string BuscaComparacao (string url)
        {
            Regex r =new Regex("\S+\D{3}[.]\D{3}\S+\D)";
        var result = r.Matches(url);
        return result[0].ToString();

        }
```

o codigo nao encontra os dados q eu mandei buscar.

Comment: Que informação está a ser pesquisada? Precisa detalhar mais a sua questão.

Comment: a expressao regular ta certa, mas ele diz que Message = "analisando \"\\s+\\d{3}[.]\\d{3}\\s+\\d)\" - Número excessivo de )'s."

Comment: Não lhe falta um parêntesis no início da expressão? _new Regex("(\S+\D{3}[.]\D{3}\S+\D)"_? Ou o parêntesis no fim está a mais?

Comment: sim, corrigi, mas nao ta retornando nada, sera que ta dando erro por ser enviada a url de um pdf

Comment: O que pretende obter com a expressão regular?

Comment: 042.964 3 (unidade concendente e codigo verificador)

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você está passando uma URL para o método. Certo?

Comment: isto C:\\AnexosEmail\\26342018013427.pdf

Comment: agora esta saindo dando a execção Message = "Argumento especificado estava fora do intervalo de valores válidos.\r\nNome do parâmetro: i" seria por que ele precisa do iis pra ler o pdf?

Comment: Sendo um caminho para um ficheiro, o que pretende com a expressão regular? Obter o nome do ficheiro? Da pasta?

Comment: obter um dado dentro do arquivo

Comment: @mateusandrade Isso é impossível. O que você está fazendo é aplicar a regex ao texto `C:\\AnexosEmail\\26342018013427.pdf`

Comment: teria que converter o pdf pra texto primeiro?

Comment: Para isso terá que utilizar uma biblioteca externa, do tipo **Docotip.pdf** ou **ITextSharp**. Da forma que está a fazer apenas está a aplicar a expressão regular no URL em si e não dentro do ficheiro.

Comment: Utilize esta biblioteca, é de fácil uso e aí depois já poderá pesquisar no texto o que precisa. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte forma

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(arquivo);
var page = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader,1);
var exp = @"\s+\d{3}[.]\d{3}\s+\d";
Regex r =new Regex(exp);
var result = r.Matches(page);
return result[0].ToString();
```

obrigado @joaomartins